# events and macros in excel vba not linking

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing excel sheet which has some macros written in modules. The sheet has various button kind of controls (check 1st scenario), but not a button (as I could not see the button control selected in even in design mode, as it is in the case of 2nd scenario).

So I was wondering what control it is and how can I link it with macros defined?? Also the coding is in modules and not in sheet, why??

I even tried to link a macro with the button created in scenario 2, but it didnt work out. I am new to excel vba, pls suggest some solution.

Also I would like to know more about macro, like why do we need a macro if we can write event based code on button click??

[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. what exactly is the question?

Comment: I could not understand what kind of control it is and how can I link it with macros? Also I have edited my post a little, if its understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off "Macro" is the generic term excel uses for VBA code. VBA is the language you are writing in when you "writing a macro". You can write VBA in a subroutine as part of the sheet object, workbook object, an independent module, class, or form. Events are part of a workbook, worksheet, or form object that can trigger code that is contained within the event's VBA routine.

Your Scenario 1 looks like maybe those are shapes drawn on the worksheet. Shapes can have "macros" assigned to them. You right click on the shape, and go to "Assign Macro". It will write the event subroutine in that worksheet's code in your Visual Basic Editor (VBE). You can then write the code inside that subroutine that was generated for you which may call other subroutines or functions that you have written in a module.

You can also tie subroutines, regardless of which object they are written in (module, worksheet, workbook) to a CommandButton, like in your second scenario. This particular button you added is an ActiveX control type button. They tend to be a bit more complicated. You should probably just go with a normal "Form Control" button as it will ask you, after you draw it, which SubRoutine you want to attach it to.

So to answer you question: Go to Developer>>Insert>>Form Control>>Button and draw it on. Then point it to your VBA subroutine that has the code you want to execute when you hit the button. Nice and simple.